# Unable to Insert data properly into database using java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle10g

I want to insert into database 4 data per second.At the same time by making each thread wait and wake up together.Then each thread goes to sleep for 1 second and whole process will repeat.Problem that i'm facing that here DATA value is not increasing and after running the program it's keep inserting data into database until forcefully stopped/terminated and after inserting 0, next data is showing 2.How can i fix this problem?

Here is the output that i'm getting as follows

```
08-JUL-16 07.43.42.721000 AM    0
08-JUL-16 07.43.42.731000 AM    2
08-JUL-16 07.43.42.731000 AM    2
08-JUL-16 07.43.42.731000 AM    2
08-JUL-16 07.43.42.731000 AM    2
.
.
.

08-JUL-16 07.43.43.815000 AM    2
08-JUL-16 07.43.43.815000 AM    2
08-JUL-16 07.43.43.825000 AM    2
.
.
```

here is my code

public class TestMainConnection {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1=new Thread(new TestingThread(),"t1");
    Thread t2=new Thread(new TestingThread(),"t2");
    Thread t3=new Thread(new TestingThread(),"t3");
    Thread t4=new Thread(new TestingThread(),"t4");
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t4.start();
}
```

}

```
public class TestingThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            doDBProcessing();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private void doDBProcessing() throws InterruptedException {
        Connection conn=null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe","SYSTEM","sd");

            String insertQuery = "Insert into k(workdate,data) values(?,?)";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
            for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
                pstmt.setTimestamp(1, getCurrentTimeStamp());
                pstmt.setLong(2, i);
                i=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }
            System.out.println("Data Successfully Uploaded");   
            pstmt.close();
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
        } catch(SQLException se) {
            se.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the right column in your output represent?

Comment: the right column is any random value. I tried with also Math.random()..